# iphone, App thinks I held the button 2 times

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton

I've go such class

```
@interface UIGestureHolder : UILongPressGestureRecognizer {

    int tag;
}
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) int tag;

@end



@implementation UIGestureHolder
@synthesize tag;
@end
```

Then I assign this to a button so that when it's held buttonheld function is appealed:

```
UIGestureHolder *longpressGesture = [[UIGestureHolder alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(buttonHeld:)];
        longpressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 1.5;

        [longpressGesture setDelegate:self];
        longpressGesture.tag=i;
        [contactButton addGestureRecognizer:longpressGesture];
        [longpressGesture release];
```

Buttonheld function:

```
-(void)buttonHeld:(id)sender
{


    int i = ((UIControl *) sender).tag;

    ......

}
```

When I hold the button for 1.5 seconds or whatever time I want, runtime tells me I held the button two times 1.5 each, why? It causes me exceptions later on.

Why runtime thinks that I hold the button two times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gesture recognizers inform you when their states change. Change the code to:

```
-(void)buttonHeld:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)longPressRecognizer 
 {
    if(longPressRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) 
    {
        int i = ((UIControl *) sender).tag;
        ......
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the button also has single tap enabled? Button behavior is to tap on it once & something happens, right?

When assigning `responder` to your button, what have you done? Try disabling that & see if you  get the same...